# Can not add a pic to an open ppt file using python

Tags: python, powerpoint

The test.pptx is a pptx file already opened, I want to add pics to its first page. The following code can run without error, but it can not add the pic

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
img_path = 'image_000.png'
f = open('test.pptx','rb')
prs = Presentation(f)
slide = prs.slides[0]
left = Inches(5)
height = Inches(5.5)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top, height=height)
```

Comment: Yes, but not using the `pptx` module.  That's actually reading and writing the file itself.  To affect an open file, you would need to use COM to drive the PowerPoint application's object model.  It's not going to be as simple as this, so you might consider how badly you need it.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Could you direct me some resource that I can learn about how to use COM to do it?

Comment: The easiest place to start would be to work out how to do what you want in VBA, since you can test things directly within PPT. Then use COM to pass the same commands to PPT. I don't use Python, so can't tell you exactly how to get access to a PPT object via COM. Perhaps someone else can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to edit the running ppt file

```
import win32com.client
PPTApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApp.Visible = True
Presentation = PPTApp.ActivePresentation
#
slidenr = Presentation.Slides.Count   
slidenr =  slidenr +1
Slide1 = Presentation.Slides.Add(slidenr,12)
# 
img_path ='myImg.png'

top = 1
left =  0

#print(top)

Pict1 = Slide1.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName=img_path,LinkToFile=False,SaveWithDocument=True, Left=left, Top=top, Width=-1, Height = -1)


Presentation.Slides(slidenr).Select()
del Presentation
```